# How do I enhance my skills?

Tags: nethack

I have read on Nethack's Wikia that it is possible to enhance my skills that are not locked...and that I free up skill points every time I gain a level.

However, every time I call #enhance, it seems that I cannot make any selection of a skill to enhance.  My listed skills are either [Unskilled] or [Basic], but none are selectable.  Seems like this should be a relatively simple issue...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As it states on the [skills page](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Skill) on the Wikihack: you must still have a number of successful uses of the skill before you can enhance it.

The number of uses is below (again from Wikihack)

```
Skill Level  - Successful Uses
Unskilled    - 0
Basic        - 20
Skilled      - 80
Expert       - 180
Master       - 320
Grand Master - 500
```

<sub>Note that successful uses are total, so to get to the next level subtract the destination level from the current level.</sub>

For example if you are `Basic` in `Dagger` you must attack with a dagger successfully 60 times (80-20) before you can raise it to `Skilled`.

You also must have a free skill slot, obtained by leveling up.

Comment: So once I use my [Basic] skill level at least 20 times, then I am able to enhance it?

Comment: @espais Once you use an [Basic] skill 20 times (successfully) you can enhance it to [Skilled].  So yes.

Comment: Are you sure that it's not 20 to get *to* basic from unskilled, and then an additional 60 (making 80 total) to get to skilled?

Comment: @StrixVaria Good catch, I've corrected that now.

Comment: "throwing"?  that's not a skill.